# Plotting discrete densities using ggplot2 and stats::density

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram

I was toying around with plotting empirical probabilities of discrete data using `ggplot2`; I am computing the probabilities for data in a vector `x` by hand using the `table(x)/length(x)` and using `geom_col` to obtain the plot.

I decided to ask my students to compare the resulting plot with the one that uses `geom_histogram` and `stat::density`. The idea was to have them realize that `stats::density` is not the correct function to use on discrete data, as it uses a smoothing kernel density estimator with the aim of providing a curve representing a continuous density.

Here is some example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5)

## Computing empirical probabilities "by hand" and plotting 
## using geom_col

x_factor <- factor(x, 1:5) # coercing to a factor to specify the support
df <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(names(table(x_factor))),
                 p = as.numeric(table(x_factor))/length(x_factor))

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = x, y = p))
```

[image]

```
## Using stats::density - this produces a plot, 
## but not correct from a statistical perspective as 
## stats:density() expects a continuous variable

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = x , y = after_stat(density)))
```

[image]

However, I found that I can adjust the code for the second plot above to represent the empirical probabilities correctly, using a `binwidth` that matches the support of the data (or equivalently select `bins` equal to the number of unique values in the data).

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = x, y = after_stat(density)), binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

Now my questions here are: why does the code above work and produce the correct plot for the empirical probabilities? How does the combination of `geom_histogram()` and `after_stat(density)` work in this example?

It also would be great if anyone is able to reproduce what is happening internally in this ggplot. I have tried to look into retrieving the computed values by inspecting the `ggplot` object associated with the plot, but I was not able to figure my way around that.

EDIT: revised question for errors in the code and to improve clarity.

Comment: Your x variable may be _mathematically_ discrete, but R does not know you want it treated as such. A numeric input variable, even if all integers, will be accepted quite happily by `stats::density` and ggplot as a continuous variable. Perhaps it would be better to illustrate the point by using `factor(x)`. This allows R to understand that the variable is discrete.

Comment: So your question is why `geom_histogram` matches your table approach, with suitable parameters? Histograms don't do any smoothing - they bin the data, count the points in the bins, and divide by the sum of the counts. It's essentially `table(cut(x)) / length(x)`. If you choose a bindwidth such that points with different `x` values don't fall in the same bin, then `table(cut(x))` has the same result as `table(x)`, and the histogram does exactly what you are doing with `table(x) / length(x)`.

Comment: I guess I'm being a overly simplistic - a histogram also takes the binwidth into consideration in calculating the y value for a particular bar. The height of a bar is `table(x) / length(x) / binwidth` to ensure that the sum of the bar areas is `1`. So it's a special case when `binwidth = 1` that the histogram y values are exactly `table(x) / length(x)`, rather than off by a factor of the binwidth.

Comment: I realized I put a couple of errors in the code example and going to revise the question!

Comment: @Allan Camer @GregorThomas thanks for the feedback. I realized I may been a bit too vague and that I put some bugs in the code.  I hope now that the question is clearer. 

@GregorThomas I also would add that the `geom_histogram()` function bins the data as you say, but it is not going to compute the proportions! Instead, it will count how many values in the data fall within a certain bin; that would be the output of only `table(x)`